# Marginalisation of probabilities

Tags: probability

I struggled to prove the below. I verified that there are no independence among the variables. I would appreciate if you could explain the steps if this is true.

$$\sum_{l} p(l \vert s)p(e \vert l) = p(e \vert s)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have that : $p(e \vert s) = \sum_{l} p(l \vert s)p(e \vert l , s) $

So your formula is true if e and s are independent given l.
As in such case : $p(e \vert l , s) =p(e \vert l )$

But in general it is false.